# What method should I apply to show this inequality

Tags: real-analysis

I was reading a solution, there's one question came out with this inequality

$\exp(\alpha \log x) \ge \frac{1}{2}(\alpha \log x)^2 $

Can someone give me a hint why this holds?

Comment: It doesn't hold. Not unless you specify the range of $x$ and $\alpha$. Note that the LHS is $x^\alpha$ and as a general rule of thumb, power law growth is faster than logarithmic growth. Plotting the two functions for a few values of $\alpha$ might be useful.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added $x \ge 0$ and $\alpha > 0$. Is there a way to prove this?

Comment: Use the following for $k=2$ and $u=\alpha\log x$, provided $\alpha\geqslant0$ and $x\geqslant1$: $$\forall u\geqslant0,\ \forall k,\ e^u=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{u^n}{n!}\geqslant\frac{u^k}{k!}$$

Comment: I see, this is a very easy way. Thanks @Did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider the function $$f(z)=e^z-\frac12 z^2$$ its derivative is always positive in the real domain.

The solution of $f(z)=0$ is given by $z_*=-2 W\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\approx -0.901201$ ($W(z)$ being Lambert function). For any value $z>z_*$, $f(z)>0$

Comment: @Did. Thanks for pointing the typo.

Answer (score 0):

<s>`You need $x \ge 1$, otherwise`</s> $x \ge 0$ is not sufficient as the inequality will fail for $x = \varepsilon$ sufficiently small and positive, and $\alpha = 1$.

Assuming $\alpha > 0$ and $x \ge 1$, then $\alpha \log x \ge 0$. It suffices to show that $\exp u \ge \frac{1}{2} u^2$ for all $u \ge 0$.

**EDIT.** A better bound is given by the unique solution $u = u_0$ to $\exp u = \frac{1}{2} u^2$. The inequality will hold whenever $\alpha \log x \ge u_0$.

Comment: $x\ge1$ may be a sufficient condition, but it is not necessary. The inequality doesn't fail for $x=0.5,\alpha=1$ for example.

Comment: @almagest Forgot to reword 'need' in my edit. Thanks.